# Get position of record in SQL result using PDO

Tags: php, sql

This query works when injected directly in SQL.. 
Any alternative to make it work with one single query, not two?

```
$Get= $db->select("SET @row_number = 0; SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num, score, points, connected FROM info WHERE id='$id' ORDER BY score DESC");
```

If I remove `SET @row_number = 0;` in the PHP it works, but it doesent give me the `num` output.. it stays blank

Comment: What DBMS? If MySQL, then upgrade to version 8 and you can simply use `row_number()`.

Comment: Im using MySQL, hmm already tried using row number..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then just use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC) num,
    score,
    points,
    connected
FROM info
WHERE id = ?
ORDER BY score DESC;
```

If you want a version which can work on earlier versions of MySQL which do not support `ROW_NUMBER`, then you could use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM info i2 WHERE i2.score >= i1.score) num
    score,
    points,
    connected
FROM info i1
WHERE id = ?
ORDER BY score DESC;
```

The above query would only work correctly if every score were unique, that is, there are no duplicate scores.